# Drawing the nodes at same level

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a json data with some nodes and the edges.

```
 {"nodes":[
            {"id":0,"title":"a","x":1200,"y":50},
            {"id":1,"title":"b","x":800,"y":200},
            {"id":2,"title":"c","x":1200,"y":200},
            {"id":3,"title":"d","x":1200,"y":400},
            {"id":4,"title":"e","x":800,"y":400},
            {"id":5,"title":"f","x":1000,"y":500}],
"edges":[
            {"source":0,"target":2},
            {"source":1,"target":3},
            {"source":2,"target":3},
            {"source":1,"target":4},
            {"source":2,"target":4},
            {"source":3,"target":5},
            {"source":4,"target":5}]
}
```

I have hard coded the "x" and "y" values here.  I want to generate those "x" and "y" values  so that the nodes of same depth remain at same level. Before hard coding the values I was generating those values using:

```
strJosn.Append("{\"id\":" + i + ",\"title\":\"" + nodeNames[i] + "\",\"x\":" + GetRandomNumber(arlRandom) + ",\"y\":" + GetRandomNumber(arlRandom));
```

my csv data looks like this:

[image]

above the first column represent the child and second column onward it is the parent nodes of the child in first column.
The corresponding  tree look like this.

[image]

How can I generate those values such that I get the nodes aligned at the same level as shown in figure?

**EDIT:**
I have stored the csv data in dataTable.

Comment: I think the problem statements needs some clarification; as undirected cycles are apparently permitted in the graph, what is the exact notion of a 'level'? Is it a requirement that the edges point to lower levels? IF so, [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) might help.

Comment: @Codor, Levels are  nothing but Y-values (ordinates) Yes edges should point to lower levels.

Comment: Where did you get this data? A `Node` class or something?

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459, from here. you can download it. I want to create my own graph with uploading the data created.

Comment: @Thomas, wew you able to find that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a class `Node`, it's not perfect but it works quite well:

```
internal class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    private Node m_child;
    public Node Child
    {
        get { return m_child; }
        set
        {
            m_child = value;
            value.Parent = this;
        }
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Node> nodes = new Dictionary<int, Node>()
        {
            {0, new Node() {Id = 0, Title = "a"}},
            {1, new Node() {Id = 1, Title = "b"}},
            {2, new Node() {Id = 2, Title = "c"}},
            {3, new Node() {Id = 3, Title = "d"}},
            {4, new Node() {Id = 4, Title = "e"}},
            {5, new Node() {Id = 5, Title = "f"}}
        };

        nodes[0].Child = nodes[2];
        nodes[1].Child = nodes[3];
        nodes[2].Child = nodes[3];
        nodes[1].Child = nodes[4];
        nodes[2].Child = nodes[4];
        nodes[3].Child = nodes[5];
        nodes[4].Child = nodes[5];


        Dictionary<int, List<Node>> nbParentNodesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Node>>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Node> valuePair in nodes)
        {
            Node parent = valuePair.Value.Parent;
            int nbOfParent = 0;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                nbOfParent++;
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            if (!nbParentNodesDictionary.ContainsKey(nbOfParent))
            {
                nbParentNodesDictionary[nbOfParent] = new List<Node>();
            }
            nbParentNodesDictionary[nbOfParent].Add(valuePair.Value);
        }

        const int yOffSet = 100;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Node>> keyValuePair in nbParentNodesDictionary)
        {
            const int xMax = 500;
            int xOffset = xMax/(keyValuePair.Value.Count+1);
            int x = 0;
            foreach (Node node in keyValuePair.Value)
            {
                x += xOffset ;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("id:" + node.Id + " title:" + node.Title + " x:" + x + " y:" + yOffSet * keyValuePair.Key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

> id:0 title:a x:166 y:0
>
> id:1 title:b x:332 y:0
>
> id:2 title:c x:250 y:100
>
> id:3 title:d x:166 y:200
>
> id:4 title:e x:332 y:200
>
> id:5 title:f x:250 y:300

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. cant we not take the input from the csv file and do it?

Comment: @Artiga we can, but maybe you could give a try ;)

Comment: sure thing. Thank you Thomas for your help. :)

Comment: I tried using csv it worked. The logic you provided sometimes giving the children's position higher than or equal to parent's level. I gave a lot of tries but I am nowhere close to it. Can you please help me out here?